# OpenIddict get token_id before response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openiddict

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("~/api/auth/login")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
{
  ...
      var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user);
      _logger.LogInformation($"User logged in (id: {user.Id})");

      // Returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.

      return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

OpenIddict creates token after SignIn method is called right? How can i access created refresh_token token_id before response is sent?

I want to associate token_id with custom device_id and save to database. Then i will allow user to revoke refresh_token with specified device.

Comment: Retrieving the token identifier before it's generated is not possible. That said, I'm about to update the token manager to allow retrieving the authentication properties you store in the ticket from the token store, which will allow you to do what you want. I'll ping you once a public version allowing that is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do with the latest RC2 packages (that you can find on the MyGet feed).

**1) Create custom entities derived from the built-in ones:**

```
public class MyApplication : OpenIddictApplication<string, MyAuthorization, MyToken>
{
    public MyApplication() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

public class MyAuthorization : OpenIddictAuthorization<string, MyApplication, MyToken>
{
    public MyAuthorization() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

public class MyScope : OpenIddictScope<string>
{
    public MyScope() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

public class MyToken : OpenIddictToken<string, MyApplication, MyAuthorization>
{
    public MyToken() => Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
}
```

**2) Update your authorization controller to store the device identifier as an authentication property:**

```
// ...
var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, properties,
    OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

ticket.SetProperty("device_id", "[the device identifier]");
// ...
```

**3) Create a custom token manager and override the `PopulateAsync` method to attach the device identifier to the token entry stored in the database:**

```
public class MyManager : OpenIddictTokenManager<MyToken>
{
    public MyManager(
        IOpenIddictTokenStore<MyToken> store,
        ILogger<OpenIddictTokenManager<MyToken>> logger)
        : base(store, logger)
    {
    }

    protected override Task PopulateAsync(MyToken token, OpenIddictTokenDescriptor descriptor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (descriptor.Properties.TryGetValue("device_id", out var identifier))
        {
            token.DeviceId = identifier;
        }

        return base.PopulateAsync(token, descriptor, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**4) Update your `Startup` class to use the new entities and the custom manager:**

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    // ...
    options.UseOpenIddict<MyApplication, MyAuthorization, MyScope, MyToken, string>();
});

services.AddOpenIddict<MyApplication, MyAuthorization, MyScope, MyToken>(options =>
{
    // ...
    options.AddTokenManager<MyManager>();
});
```

Comment: Is this approach still the same for newer versions, or has it changed since then? I also need to get the token before sending a SignInResult.

Comment: It still works in 1.0 and 2.0 RTM but won't be supported in 3.0, as it will no longer use `AuthenticationTicket` and `AuthenticationProperties`. Also, you can't get the token before returning a `SignInResult` because it's precisely what triggers an authorization response and creates a token under the hood. Is there a particular reason you need the token at that stage?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for the quick reply! I'm currently using version 2.0.1 and I need it to cast the OpenIdConnectResponse to a custom DTO. If you're saying there is no way to get the token before response, then maybe I could make use of AOP or a response filter.

Comment: Depending on why you need to return a custom DTO, there may be way better options. Is it to return a custom property?

Comment: Not necessarily a custom property. I am using swagger codegen which generates for `OpenIdConnectResponse` a typescript model, which has e.g. the property `accessToken`. But the response from the server has this particular property as `access_token` (notice the underscore). So if I map to a custom DTO before response, I can get around this mapping inconsistency.